# Uncaught ReferenceError: messageRef is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using The Code Given Below To store my html contact form data in firebase

```
var firestore =  firebase.firestore();

var messagesRef = firestore.collection("BookingData");


//listen for submit
document.getElementById('bookingForm').addEventListener('submit',submitForm);

function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
var email = getInputVal('email');
var packageFields = getInputVal('packageFields');
var name = getInputVal('name');
var phone = getInputVal('phone');
var date = getInputVal('date');

saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date);
}

// function to get form values

 function getInputVal(id) {
return document.getElementById(id).value;
 }

//save messages

function saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date) {

  messageRef.add({
   email:email,
   packageFields:packageFields,
   name:name,
   phone:phone,
   date:date
   }).then(function(docRef) {
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});

}
```

It Gives the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: messageRef is not defined
>       at saveMessage (bookingSubmit.js:47)

how can I solve it? Please help...

How To Define ***messageRef***...??

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You declare `messagesRef` (plural) and then call `messageRef.add(...` (singular). Since these two don't match, the compiler complains about the undefined `messageRef`. You'll want to  `messagesRef.add(...` (plural) too.

Comment: How Can I Make messagesRef.add(... Plural

Comment: By plural he meant to put a  "S" on the messageRef.add()

Comment: You Mean messageRef.adds(... How To Put "S" on messageRef.add() ...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Now

```
var messagesRef = firestore.collection("BookingData");


//listen for submit
document.getElementById('bookingForm').addEventListener('submit',submitForm);

function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
var email = getInputVal('email');
var packageFields = getInputVal('packageFields');
var name = getInputVal('name');
var phone = getInputVal('phone');
var date = getInputVal('date');

saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date);
}

// function to get form values

 function getInputVal(id) {
return document.getElementById(id).value;
 }

//save messages

function saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date) {
// problem was here 
  messagesRef.add({
   email:email,
   packageFields:packageFields,
   name:name,
   phone:phone,
   date:date
   }).then(function(docRef) {
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});

}
```